# Where can I find the source code of Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: rpi-source

I am planning to start some research on the source codes of a number of middle-ware systems. Raspberry pi is one of those. But I cannot find the source code for Raspbian Jessie. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: You can read more about it at: http://raspbian.org/RaspbianDocumentation

Comment: I don't believe you have tried looking.

Answer (score 3):

The source code of official **foundation** Raspbian images
is scattered over few places :

- source of the customised Linux kernel : http://www.github.com/raspberrypi/linux
- source of most packages : use the `apt-get source` command
- source of some modified packages : browse https://github.com/raspberrypi?tab=repositories

Don't forget that foundation images also include closed-source
software (esp. the mandatory bootloader , Oracles JVM etc.) !